# recursive method play needs result type

Tags: scala, playframework

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
//Count.scala
object Count extends Controller{
  def play = Action { request =>
    val videoId = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("videoId").head
    val Video = new Video()
    Video.incrementPlayCount(videoId)
    Ok("Success!")
  }
}
```

これは何が原因でエラーが出ているのですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

原因は `play` というメソッド名です。メソッド名を変更すればコンパイルが通るはずです。

以下推測混じりですが詳しく。

Play は conf/routes を元にコード生成を行っていますが、その生成されたコードでコンパイルエラーが起きています。生成されたコードは `target/scala-<version>/src_managed` ディレクトリにあります。

今回エラーの原因は `play` というメソッド名にあります。推測ですが、`play` はパッケージ名などにも使われているため、それと衝突したためにこのエラーが発生しているものと思います。

エラーメッセージが、「再帰メソッド `play` には戻り値の型が必要です」ですが、生成されたコードを見たところ再帰しておらず、正しいエラーメッセージとは言えないので、それは Scala コンパイラのバグなのかもしれません。

なお、Play 2.4.0-M3 で試したところエラーは発生しませんでした。どの修正かまでは追っていませんが、なんらかの対策がすでに取られたのかもしれません。

Comment: メソッド名を変えたらうまくいきました。なるほど、ありがとうございました。